# How to display a scrollview and pageControl within a navigation view controller?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uipagecontrol

I am new to iOS development and have been fiddling with this for a while and can't seem to find an answer or get it to work.

I have a navigation controller as the root view controller of my app. There is a table and selecting a cell will open a view that I want to be scrollable with page control.

I make a new subclass of UIViewController, call it PagingViewController. In interface builder, I just drag in a UIScrollView and a UIPageControl and lay it out appropriately on the screen.

When I push the PagingViewController onto the navigation controller, the UIPageControl does not display.
When I modify AppDelegate.m to use PagingViewController as the root view controller and start the app, the UIPageControl does display.

I'm trying to figure out why UIPageControl does not display. I think it has something to do with being used in conjunction with the navigation controller, but other answers and posts I've read seem to indicate that it is indeed possible.

And yes, in both cases, I initiate the PagingViewController in the same way. I am confused. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please post some code so that we can help you. I would help to see how you push the PagingViewController object and how you init it. Cheers!